# Check panadas dataframe for singular matrices

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use pandas scatter_matrix for displaying dataframe contents eg:

```
scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6, 6), diagonal='kde')
```

However I get a singular matrix error as the scatter_matrix with kde option code tries to invert a covariance matrix of the data where there is no covariance.

```
#see pands.tools.plotting.scatter_matrix
n = df.columns.size
mask = notnull(df)
for i, a in zip(range(n), df.columns):
    for j, b in zip(range(n), df.columns):
        if i == j:
            values = df[a].values[mask[a].values]
            from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
            y = values
            try:
                #the line below calls linalg.inv(self._data_covariance)
                #which throws the LinAlgError
                gkde = gaussian_kde(y)
            except LinAlgError as e:
                logger.debug("Error, data: {0}".format(y))
```

Is there a way I could re-create the dataframe so that matrices combinations with no covariance are removed?

Answer (score 0):

What helped me is go through your matrix and drop any suspicious columns and check the rank of the matrix with `np.linalg.matrix_rank(X)` if your matrix is full rank after you dropped a column you should be fine and the column was redundant.